# Error with global variables in Java

Tags: java, variables, global

I'm declaring this global variable in a class:

```
public class pacmanIcaveBean implements pacmanIcaveLocal {
    public static String archivoPRTOriginal = "";

    public void pacman() {
        pacmanIcaveBean.archivoPRTOriginal = "C:\\Ruta.prt";
    }
}
```

But I'm calling it in other class like this:

```
public class Generador {
    public void generar {
        System.out.println(pacmanIcaveBean.archivoPRTOriginal);
    }
}
```

And it doesn't show me `C:\\Ruta.prt`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you call the `pacman()` method?

Comment: Please format your code using the utilities provided by the editor.

Comment: What output is it showing?

Comment: Output shows nothing, like the first value assignation.

Comment: In `pacman()` add `System.out.println("value has been set");`, run your code, and see if the value has been set. You could also step through the code with a debugger to watch the order of execution.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? If you downvote then leave a comment explaining the reason for the downvote - how are new users to learn how to write a good question otherwise?  Come on, SO, you used to be better than this.  I'm not a new user and don't understand why there are so many downvotes without a single vote to close.

Comment: I can´t call the pacman() method becouse the complete process would start again, do you thing if I declare another method in the pacmanIcaveBean class getting pacmanIcaveBean.archivoPRTOriginal var and calling it in Generador class would work?

Comment: what complete process?

Comment: This code it´s not just a test application. The first class used is pacmanIcaveBean, it calls another and so on until it calls the Generador class.

Comment: adding those classes would help us.

Comment: @Paul sorry, I´m new in this. Besides, english it´s not my native language.

Comment: @Paul oh yes i agree but why SO has fallen is for another place.

Comment: No need to apologize, Giovani, your English is very good and more than adequate to describe the problem.  I was saying that I didn't understand why your question received downvotes because it seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't set the archivoPRTOriginal to the value C:\Ruta.prt yet. You need to call the pacman() method to set the value first.

Answer (score 0):

`pacmanIcaveBean.archivoPRTOriginal = "C:\\Ruta.prt"` is placed in `pacmanIcaveBean`'s constructor - i.e., it will only be called when you call `new pacmanIcaveBean()`. Since your code snippet does not call it, that line of code is never invoked, and `archivoPRTOriginal` remains `""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class pacmanIcaveBean implements pacmanIcaveLocal
{
  public static String archivoPRTOriginal = "";
  public void pacman()
  {
    pacmanIcaveBean.archivoPRTOriginal = "C:\\Ruta.prt";
  }
}

public class Generador
{
  public void generar
  {
    //call pacman method
    new pacmanIcaveBean().pacman(); 
    System.out.println( pacmanIcaveBean.archivoPRTOriginal );
  }
}
```

Comment: how not? i invoked the public class

Comment: oh yea duh. sorry was in a rush forgot that thanks @Paul

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess the pacman method is not executed at the time the system.out.println is processed.

Just associate the string value to the global variable when you declare it if you want to be sure that it contains the value expected.

```
public static String archivoPRTOriginal = "C:\Ruta.prt";
```

Ambiguous question, hard to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this would work?

```
public class pacmanIcaveBean implements pacmanIcaveLocal{

public static String archivoPRTOriginal = "";

public void pacman(){

pacmanIcaveBean.archivoPRTOriginal = "C:\\Ruta.prt";

}

public String valores(){

  String ruta=pacmanIcaveBean.archivoPRTOriginal;

  return ruta;
  }
 }

 public class Generador{

 public void generar{

  pacmanIcaveBean Obj= new pacmanIcaveBean(); 
   System.out.println( Obj.valores() );
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution!

```
public class pacmanIcaveBean {

private static String rutaCopiar = "";

public static String getRutaCopiar() {
    return rutaCopiar;
}

public static void setRutaCopiar(String rutaCopiar) {
    pacmanIcaveBean.rutaCopiar = rutaCopiar;
}

public void pacman() {

    pacmanIcaveBean.setRutaCopiar("C:\\Ruta.prt");

   }
}

public class Generador {

public void generar() {

    new pacmanIcaveBean().pacman();
    System.out.println(pacmanIcaveBean.getRutaCopiar());

}
}
```